# get two input files from CompareEditorInput

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, beyondcompare

My requirement is to use a new external compare tool for certain type of file extensions in eclipse RCP product.
For other files eclipse default compare editor should be used.
In order to achieve this , I am using ASPECTJ to hook to eclipse default compare editor method .  In my aspect method I am validating the file which is selected, If the file is a particular type I am trying to call my external compare tool or else continue with using eclipse default editor.

I am not able to get two files( that is left and right input file) from the compareEditorInput Object which is a parameter. 
Is there any way to get two input files so that i can pass to my external compare tool??

Answer (score 0):

The compare editor itself does not require that the input comes from files, nor does the base `CompareEditorInput` class.

Subclasses of `CompareEditorInput` such as `ResourceCompareInput` do work from files so you may be able to get the input from them. But these are internal classes and not part of the API.

Comment: Thanks! for replying..is there any way i get those two files or input streams just before default compare editor  is launched??

Comment: The editor is launched from several places you would have to look at them all the see what is available.